# How do I get free music on the iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios

How can I get free songs to listen to on my iPhone?

I use iOS 6 and an iPhone 4.

Comment: Welcome, we like questions, but to keep our place organized (so others can find it) please ask one question at time. You can listen to free songs of your choice all day long on Spotify.com !

Answer (score 1):

Apple's iTunes service offers free downloads of podcasts and usually several free songs a week. This way you can start building free music without needing a computer.

Many artists also distribute free music you can download into iTunes and then sync it to your iPhone.

If you want to list more of what exactly you seek, we might be able to provide a better answer.